# IdentityServer4 and Hybrid flow

Tags: identityserver4

We have the following structure:

UI -> API1 -> API2 -> API3 -> DB

In this structure we want to authorize user on every step, so we used
the following design:

- Client -> UI with Scope to API1
- API resource -> API1 API2 API3

Now when the User logs in to Identity Server by UI, the Client gets an
Id token and Reference token.

This Reference token will be exchanged by the Middle layer on the API1. As the token has scope to API1 it can access API1 endPoints.

My question, will it be able to call API2 with the token it got from the Identityserver?

Answer (score 2):

Unless the **Access Token** has includes scopes for  API2 and API3 you will not automatically gain access to API2 and API3.

You can avoid having to add API2 and API3 scopes to the original token by using an **Extension Grant**.  More information can be found here: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/extension_grants.html#refextensiongrants